# Водяной знак с ресайзом и прозрачностью

Tags: gd, php, функции

Никак не могу осилить функцию. От нее требуется сделать ресайз водяного знака (в png) до указанной пропорции, сохранить прозрачность png и сделать сам знак полупрозрачным (степень прозрачности указывается в параметрах функции). Вот, что получилось:

```
function watermark_image($imgRes, $dimensions, $options) {
$defaults = array(
    'string' => '',
    'file' => '/img/watermark.png',
    'scale' => 50,
    'opacity' => 30,
    'corners' => 10, //Отступы
     'opacity' => 100
);
$options = array_merge($defaults, $options);
if (isset($options['string']) && strlen($options['string']) > 3)
    $watermark = imagecreatefromstring($imgRes);
else
    $watermark = self::open_image($options['file']);

// Приведение значений прозрачности и увеличения к интервалу
// от 1 до 100
$scale = min(max($options['scale'], 1), 100) / 100;
$opacity = min(max($options['opacity'], 1), 100);

// Вычисление разницы в размерах между оригинальным изображением
// и изображением "водяного знака"
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);

$size_difference = $dimensions['width'] / $watermark_width;

if ($watermark_height * $size_difference > $dimensions['height']) {
    $size_difference = $dimensions['height'] / $watermark_height;
}
// Вычисление новых размеров "водяного знака"
$scale_ratio = $size_difference * $scale;

$watermark_new_width = round($watermark_width * $scale_ratio);
$watermark_new_height = round($watermark_height * $scale_ratio);
                $x = $dimensions['width'] - $watermark_new_width - $options['corners'];
        $y = $dimensions['height'] - $watermark_new_height - $options['corners'];
// Корректировка положения "водяного знака", чтобы он целиком
// уместился на оригинальном изображении
if ($x + $watermark_new_width > $dimensions['width']) {
    $x = $dimensions['width'] - $watermark_new_width - $options['corners'];
} else if ($x < 0) {
    $x = $options['corners'];
}

if ($y + $watermark_new_height > $dimensions['height']) {
    $y = $dimensions['height'] - $watermark_new_height - $options['corners'];
} else if ($y < 0) {
    $y = $options['corners'];
}

$wm = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_new_width, $watermark_new_height);
imagecolortransparent($wm, imagecolorallocatealpha($wm, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($wm, false);
imagesavealpha($wm, true);

imagecopymerge($wm,$watermark,0,0,0,0,$watermark_width,$watermark_height,$opacity);

imagecopyresampled(
  $imgRes, $wm, $x, $y, 0, 0, $watermark_new_width, $watermark_new_height, $watermark_width, $watermark_height
  );

#imagedestroy($wm);
imagedestroy($watermark);
return $imgRes;
```

Проблема в том, что получается только кусок значка с затемненным фоном и черный квадрат в остальной части вычисленного размера знака. Если чуть изменить, то можно получить простановку водяного знака с учетом прозрачности png, но при этом сам знак остается не полупрозрачным. Нужна помощь! Заранее спасибо!

Comment: convert image.png -gravity SouthEast watermark.png -composite out.png :)

Comment: )) Ну, имелось ввиду решение на php) Точнее помощь в допиливании функции...